# Image not appearing in Default.aspx

Tags: asp.net, image

I am trying to get the default.aspx page, with nothing but a login screen to display a logo above the login screen.  The logo is saved into an images folder in the main directory of the project.  The image is in a total of two locations, one before login, and on a different page after.

Before the user logs in, you can not see the image, basically getting the image not found graphic.  Yet the user gets the exact same image, from the exact same file, after they log in.  If they then log back out, the image will appear once but if you reload the page, it goes back to image not found.  Further complicating issues is the fact that it will work when running it for debug, yet not when I try to access it through a browser.

I have tried putting the image in various directories, as well as different parts of the default page and still no luck.  The line declaring my image is

```
<asp:Image ImageUrl="~/Images/CCA.jpg" runat="server" AlternateText="CCA Logo"/>
```

Any suggestions?

Edit:
After trying a few things, I have looked into the inspect element for the page and found that the image is set to the right directory path (http://server/Portal/PortalSite/Images/CCA.jpg).  When the image works (after login) I can follow the link to get just the image.  Yet when it does not work, It takes me back to the page

```
http://server/Portal/PortalSite/Default.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fPortal%2fPortalSite%2fImages%2fCCA.jpg
```

Could this be a problem with the url pathing?

Edit:
Also, this may be a silly question, but since Im new, do I need any sort of setup in the resulting default.aspx.vb file?  It currently only has the login redirect information.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using forms auth you might want to add a location tag in your web.config file that allows access to the images folder.

```
 <configuration>
     <location path="Images">
        <system.web>
          <authorization>
            <allow users="*" />
          </authorization>
        </system.web>
      </location>
     <appSettings/>
     <system.web>

     <!-- other stuff -->
     </system.web>
    </configuration>
```

Or you could try putting a web.config file in the folder(s) in question.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <allow users="*" />
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Any place where I should put it in my web.config file? Or will anywhere do?

Comment: @user1816892 the location section should be a child of the configuration section. i'll modify my answer a bit.

Comment: @user1816892 do a hard refresh just to be sure. If your issue was based on forms auth, this should solve it.

Comment: Thats what I thought, but it didn't work. Could the directories be affecting it?  The Image directory is Portal/PortalSite/Images.  Portal Contains the .sln file and PortalSite contains all the folders for the project, such as Images and App_Data.

Comment: @user1816892 i've modified my answer again. you could try putting a web.config file in the affected folder(s). add the markup i've specified.

Comment: Still no luck.  I created a new web.config file with the same code you put in your edit and deleted the modifications to the main web.config file.  Nothing happened.

Comment: Also, this may be a silly question, but since Im new, do I need any sort of setup in the resulting default.aspx.vb file?

Comment: Also of note, when it puts up the image not found icon, it redirects to //server/Portal/PortalSite/Default.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fPortal%2fPortalSite%2fImage‌​s%2fCCA.jpg, instead of the proper directory